# ld: linker error

Tags: c, build, linker, shared-libraries, ld

ld: foo.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `bar' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

I recompile with -fPIC and it still produces this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versions of your compiler and linker? Perhaps your problem is related to this bug, that seems to be fixed now: http://sources.redhat.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=584?